# Android UI: designing Alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Hi I am trying to design alert dialog as below [image]

I did the basic design as follows:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.share);
    final EditText message = new EditText(context);
    message.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    message.setLines(10);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        (int) LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        (int) LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Please give suggestion to me, how can I achieve this with alert dialog or another way

Comment: You can do a popup window which is designed in xml and then inflated.

Comment: Follow example mentioned here http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/.

Comment: any suggestion  doing with  alertwindow

Comment: @curious how to give the background color to textfield ex- in the image on top "post on your wall"

Comment: <LinearLayout backgroud color="blue"><LinearLayout orientation =horizontal>add facebook image and Text(make text color white)</LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>. This is not exact syntax but conceptually try this inside the Layout for AlertDialog. Tell me if it seems confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my tutorial.

http://www.androidianlabs.com/custom-android-dialogs.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: No problem! I just like it because you can call the dialog from wherever just like a stock dialog. Happy coding!

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm redoing the website. Ill post a fresh link when finished.

Comment: its been one and half year after your comment, still link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can create custom Alert Dialog Box like above . You have to use ***Dialog*** class.

You can use Dialog class like this

```
// custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Title...");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
```

For more detail  refer this link[Custom Dialog Box](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Comment: ..how to give the background color to textfield ex- in the image on top "post on your wall"

Answer (score 0):

You need to customise the layout in an xml file and you need to inflate it.
You can inflate your xml file using something like below

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
Context mContext;
mContext = YourClassName.this;
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customised_dialog_layout,null);
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setView(layout);
alertDialog = builder.create(); 
alertDialog.show();
```

customised_dialog_layout is your customised layout for the required popup